# ORDER BY not working when using CASE WHEN, but works without it?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following select statement where I am trying to order my results in a specific way, specifically the hierarchy of the department. However when I add cases, my ORDER BY stops working and gives me an error:

> ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if the statement
>   contains a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator.

I don't know why this is happening because I am selecting all in each SELECT statement.

```
Select * FROM AccountAdminTable Where CollegeCode = 'A10' AND AdminLevel LIKE 'Account Administrator'
Union
Select * FROM AccountAdminTable Where CollegeCode = 'A10' AND AdminLevel LIKE 'Department Head/Director'
Union
Select * FROM AccountAdminTable Where CollegeCode = 'A10' AND AdminLevel LIKE 'Dean/Vice President'
Order By AdminLevel ASC
```

This doesn't work:

```
Select * FROM AccountAdminTable Where CollegeCode = 'A' AND AdminLevel LIKE 'Account Administrator'
Union
Select * FROM AccountAdminTable Where CollegeCode = 'A' AND AdminLevel LIKE 'Department Head/Director'
Union
Select * FROM AccountAdminTable Where CollegeCode = 'A' AND AdminLevel LIKE 'Dean/Vice President'
Order By Case
    When AdminLevel = 'Account Administrator' Then 1
    When AdminLevel = 'Department Head/Director' Then 2
    When AdminLevel = 'Dean/Vice President' Then 3
    Else 4 End ASC
```

Any help is greatly appreciated! Below is some sample data.

```
College Code| AdminLevel               | Name
A           | Account Administrator    | Bob
A           | Department Head/Director | Tim
A           | Dean/Vice President      | Jeff
B           | Account Administrator    | Gary
B           | Department Head/Director | Phil
B           | Dean/Vice President      | John
C           | Account Administrator    | Bill
C           | Account Administrator    | Larry
```

Comment: The error is pretty clear.   You are ordering by a CASE.   Because you are using UNION, you must include the CASE in each of the SELECTs.

Comment: Use a subquery or a CTE, and order in the outer query

Comment: You *probably* want to use `UNION ALL` too, as `UNION` will cause the data engine to only return distinct results; which can be a costly operation.

Comment: Aside: You could use a _simple case_ rather than a _searched case_ since you are only checking the value of a single column against a series of string literals: `case AdminLevel when 'Account Administrator' then 1 when 'Department Head/Director' then 2 ...`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have 2 options:

- Use a derived table to use the CASE in the ORDER BY.

```
SELECT *
FROM(
         Select * FROM AccountAdminTable Where CollegeCode = 'A' AND AdminLevel LIKE 'Account Administrator'
        Union
        Select * FROM AccountAdminTable Where CollegeCode = 'A' AND AdminLevel LIKE 'Department Head/Director'
        Union
        Select * FROM AccountAdminTable Where CollegeCode = 'A' AND AdminLevel LIKE 'Dean/Vice President'
        )t
Order By Case 
        When AdminLevel = 'Account Administrator' Then 1
        When AdminLevel = 'Department Head/Director' Then 2
        When AdminLevel = 'Dean/Vice President' Then 3
        Else 4 End ASC;
```

*Or add a column that defines the order.

```
Select *, 1 AS OrderCol FROM AccountAdminTable Where CollegeCode = 'A' AND AdminLevel LIKE 'Account Administrator'
Union
Select *, 2 AS OrderCol FROM AccountAdminTable Where CollegeCode = 'A' AND AdminLevel LIKE 'Department Head/Director'
Union
Select *, 3 AS OrderCol FROM AccountAdminTable Where CollegeCode = 'A' AND AdminLevel LIKE 'Dean/Vice President'
Order By OrderCol;
```

Either way, you might want to change the UNION into UNION ALL to improve performance. Unless you're actually eliminating duplicates.

Comment: BUT you may want to go 2nd route only because when QA-ing your own code a few days, weeks, months from now; you will have much better idea as what order by is doing and on what value(s).

Comment: Honestly the UNION here is just a performance hindrance. It is the same table in each query.

Comment: @SeanLange I agree, unless there's the remote case where duplicates are present in the table. That, of course, would mean a greater problem.

Comment: True there, but a simple distinct could solve that.

Answer (score 6):

You know, you really don't need to use a UNION at all here.  Since all your SELECTS are from the same table, you could just do this (note, abbreviations used in my pseudo code below.   use correct values in your code, obviously):

```
Select * FROM AccountAdminTable 
Where CollegeCode = 'A'
AND AdminLevel IN ('Account Administrator','Dept HD','Dean/VP')
ORDER BY CASE {Your CASE Expression}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option to write your query is this:

```
SELECT AccountAdminTable.*
FROM AccountAdminTable
INNER JOIN (VALUES
    (1, 'Account Administrator'),
    (2, 'Dept HD'),
    (3, 'Dean/VP')
) AS vlist(Sort, AdminLevel) ON AccountAdminTable.AdminLevel = vlist.AdminLevel
WHERE CollegeCode = 'A'
ORDER BY vlist.Sort
```

Or better, create a table for admin levels and reference it via foreign key.